# use of singular value decomposition for dimensionality reduction

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction

I am very new to machine learning. I just understand dimesionality reduction from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994431/what-does-dimensionality-reduction-mean/1994481#1994481)

I am trying to understand [this](http://john.blitzer.com/papers/emnlp06.pdf) paper. Here they use Singular value decomposition to reduce dimension. Can anybody explain in very simple language what is singular value decomposition?I do not need the steps for doing it, i just want to feel the output and it's relation to input matrix. And how it can be used in dimensionality reduction.

Comment: Welcome to our site.  Often it is most useful to you when you begin with a [search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=svd+dimension+reduction).

Comment: I found that before but wanted something that is easily explained with some practical example. i found http://www.cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/0607/recommend/recommender/svd.html this . This was really helpfull. Thanks @whuber